# Does silicone hard as plastic exist?

Tags: polymers

I saw rubber-like silicones. Are there types of silicone that can be used in injection molding and once the process is finished - become as rigid as, let's say PVC? At the same time they should have all(/majority) of silicone's properties (citing Wikipedia):

- Low thermal conductivity
- Low chemical reactivity
- Low toxicity
- Thermal stability (constancy of properties over a wide temperature range of −100 to 250 °C)
- Does not support microbiological growth
- Resistance to oxygen, ozone, and ultraviolet (UV) light
- High gas permeability

If such silicones exist - what are their names/formulas?

Comment: Homework. Hint: What generally limits the application temperature range of polymer types?

Comment: The answer is unlikely to be as simple as you might think. Most properties of material involving polymers are determined by the additives and means of production which allow a very wide range of possible properties. While, for example, PVC is usually a rigid, stiff material, with the right plasticisers it can be made into a flexible, soft tube. The same is probably true for silicones.

Comment: If there are so many options - name at least/just one. I need something as rigid as a regular PVC pipe.